# CSS Animation not showing all content

Tags: html, css

So I found nice CSS-only news ticker [here](http://codepen.io/ryan-w-moore/pen/fxrhl), I have also implemented it:

http://jsbin.com/xitazujuko/edit?html,css,output

My problem is that it only shows 4 news lines instead of 6 even though it in HTML I have input 6:

```
<li>News line 1</li>
<li>News line 2</li>
<li>News line 3</li>
<li>News line 4</li>
<li>News line 5</li>
<li>News line 6</li>
```

Can anybody tell what I am missing here?

Comment: That's because you only have 4 states defined in your css animation i.e. `margintop: -30px
        }
        50% {
            margin-top: -60px
        }
        75% {
            margin-top: -90px}`. You need to divide this into 6 parts and then adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this section of the code:

```
@keyframes ticker {
    0%   {margin-top: 0}
    25%  {margin-top: -30px}
    50%  {margin-top: -60px}
    75%  {margin-top: -90px}
    100% {margin-top: 0}
}
```

change it to `20%` points and add one more:

```
@keyframes ticker {
    0%   {margin-top: 0}
    20%  {margin-top: -30px}
    40%  {margin-top: -60px}
    60%  {margin-top: -90px}
    80%  {margin-top: -120px}
    100% {margin-top: 0}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this bit of code, you've only divided the height into 4;

```
@keyframes  ticker {
    0% {
        margin-top: 0
    }
    16.66666% {
        margin-top: -30px
    }
    33.33333% {
        margin-top: -60px
    }
    50% {
        margin-top: -90px
    }
    66.66666% {
        margin-top: -120px
    }
    83.33333% {
        margin-top: -150px
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: 0px
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change your key frames as below to show last 5 news( and change for other number you want ) :

```
    @keyframes  ticker {
    0% {
        margin-top: 0
    }
    20% {
        margin-top: -30px
    }
    40% {
        margin-top: -60px
    }
    60% {
        margin-top: -90px
    }
    80% {
        margin-top: -120px/* this */
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: 0
    }
}
```

also you can change timing as you want!

```
    .news ul {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    animation: ticker 25s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;/* now set to 25s */
    -webkit-user-select: none
}
```

sorry for my poor English :)